# UITableView reloads incorrectly after removeObjectAtIndex and reloadData

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` which has data from an `NSMutableArray`.

When calling `removeObjectAtIndex` on the array and then `reloadData` on the table, the cell is removed fine, but then scrolling shows the table hasn't reloaded properly.

The code I am using is:

```
    [_squadArray removeObjectAtIndex:myIndex;

    [[self tableView] reloadData];
```

This is what the table looks like afterwards:

[image]

FYI, the table should be full and not stop where it stops.

Update: `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *MyIdentifier;
    MyIdentifier = @"cell";
    ClubSquadPlayerTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

    PFObject *object = [_squadArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.playerNameLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", [object valueForKey:@"first_name"], [object valueForKey:@"last_name"]];
    cell.squadNumberLabel.text = [[object valueForKey:@"squad_number"] stringValue];
    cell.positionLabel.text = [object valueForKey:@"position"];
    if ([[object valueForKey:@"fitness_status"] isEqualToString:@"Fit"])
    {
        cell.fitnessStatusImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"fit"];
    } else if ([[object valueForKey:@"fitness_status"] isEqualToString:@"Doubtful"])
    {
        cell.fitnessStatusImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"doubtful"];
    } else if ([[object valueForKey:@"fitness_status"] isEqualToString:@"Injured"])
    {
        cell.fitnessStatusImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"injured"];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Can you show us your cellForRowAtIndex method? Also - are you allowing the user to delete items from the tableView or are you doing this in some other way? lastly - the numberOfRowsInSection method I assume gets its count from the myArray property?

Comment: please post the cellforindexpath method

Comment: Thank you for the input. Have updated initial question. Users can delete items using the standard swipe to delete. And yes, the array count sets the number of rows.

Comment: @Tander any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me like your problems can be solved by [Parse's own UI](http://blog.parse.com/announcements/introducing-the-new-parseui-for-ios/).

The Parse UI version of a `UITableViewController` is a `PFQueryTableViewController`. You can still use your custom cells and outlets, but the controller is a bit different.

In this case your issue will be solved by the `[yourTable loadObjects]` function which allows you to update your table from the `PFQuery`.

You set up the `PFQueryTableViewController` directly from a `PFQuery` without arrays. See more [here](https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFQueryTableViewController.html).

Answer (score 0):

When you try to remove the object  as i saw it have santax error

Your code is

```
     [_squadArray removeObjectAtIndex:myIndex;

[[self tableView] reloadData];
```

But it should be

```
    [_squadArray removeObjectAtIndex:myIndex];

[[self tableView] reloadData];
```

There were ] missing

Comment: This was a typo. Thanks anyway though